# Why does object.__new__ accept parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instantiation, metaclass, object-construction

Besides the obvious asking "again" about `__new__` and `__init__` in Python - I can ensure, I know what it does. I'll demonstrate some strange and to my opinion undocumented behavior, for which I seek professional help :).

---

## Background

I'm implementing several features like abstract methods, abstract classes, must-override methods, singletone behavior, slotted classes (automatic inference of `__slots__`) and mixin classes (deferred slots) using a user-defined meta-class called `ExtendedType`. The following code can be found as a whole  at [pyTooling/pyTooling](https://github.com/pyTooling/pyTooling/blob/dev/pyTooling/MetaClasses/__init__.py?ts=2#L293) on the development branch.

Thus, the presented question is a stripdown and simplified variant demonstrating the strange behavior of `object.__new__`.

## Idea

Depending on the internal algorithms of `ExtendedType`, it might decide a class `A` is *abstract*. If so, the `__new__` method is replaced by a dummy method raising an exception (`AbstractClassError`). Later, when a class `B(A)` inherits from `A`, the meta-class might come to the decision, `B` isn't abstract anymore, thus we want to allow the object creation again and allow calling for the original `__new__` method. Therefore, the original method is preserved as a field in the class.

To simplify the internal algorithms for the abstractness decision, the meta-class implements a boolean named-parameter `abstract`.

```py
class AbstractClassError(Exception):
    pass

class M(type):
  # staticmethod
  def __new__(cls,  className, baseClasses, members, abstract):
    newClass = type.__new__(cls, className, baseClasses, members)
        
    if abstract:
      def newnew(cls, *_, **__):
        raise AbstractClassError(f"Class is abstract")
            
      # keep original __new__ and exchange it with a dummy method throwing an error
      newClass.__new_orig__ = newClass.__new__
      newClass.__new__ = newnew
    else:
      # 1. replacing __new__ with original (preserved) method doesn't work
      newClass.__new__ = newClass.__new_orig__

    return newClass


class A(metaclass=M, abstract=True):
  pass


class B(A, abstract=False):
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg = arg

b = B(5)
```

When instantiating `B` we'll try two cases:

1. with a single parameter: `b = B(5)`
   Error message:

   ```
   TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
   ```
2. without a parameter: `b = B()`
   Error message:

   ```
   TypeError: B.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
   ```

The error message of the latter case is expected, because `__init__` of `B` expects an argument `arg`. The strange behavior is in case 1, where it reports `object.__new__()` takes no additional parameters except of the type.

So let's investigate if swapping methods worked correctly:

```py
print("object.__new__ ", object.__new__)
print("A.__new_orig__ ", A.__new_orig__)
print("A.__new__      ", A.__new__)
print("B.__new__      ", B.__new__)
```

Results:

```
object.__new__  <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE30EDD0C0>
A.__new_orig__  <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE30EDD0C0>
A.__new__       <function M.__new__.<locals>.newnew at 0x000001CF11AE5A80>
B.__new__       <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE30EDD0C0>
```

So, the preserved method in `__new_orig__` is identical to `object.__new__` and is again the same after swapping back the `__new__` method in class `B`.

## Comparing with Ordinary Classes

Let's take two classes `X` and `Y(X)` and instantiate them:

```py
class X:
    pass


class Y(X):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

y = Y(3)
```

Of cause this will work, but are the `__new__` methods different?

```py
object.__new__  <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE3B61D0C0>
A.__new_orig__  <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE3B61D0C0>
A.__new__       <function M.__new__.<locals>.newnew at 0x000001CD1FB459E0>
B.__new__       <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE3B61D0C0>
X.__new__       <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE3B61D0C0>
Y.__new__       <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE3B61D0C0>
```

Also `X` and `Y` use the same `__new__` method as `B` or `object`.

So let's instantiate `Y` and `B` and compare results:

```py
print("Y.__new__      ", Y.__new__)
y = Y(3)
print("y.arg          ", y.arg)

print("B.__new__      ", B.__new__)
b = B(5)
print("b.arg          ", y.arg)
```

Results:

```
Y.__new__       <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE3B61D0C0>
y.arg           3
B.__new__       <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFE3B61D0C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\newIstKomisch.py", line 67, in <module>
    b = B(5)
        ^^^^
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

**Question 1: Why does **new** accept parameters for Y, but not for B?**

## Creating Objects

When an object is created, the `__call__` method of the meta-class is executed, which roughly translates to:

```py
class M(type):
  ...

  def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    inst = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    inst.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return inst
```

It first calls `__new__` to create an instance and then it calls `__init__` to initialize the object. One might argue and say: "maybe there is magic behavior in **call**" to check if  a build-in or user-defined method is called"...

Let's quickly check how `object.__new__` behaves:

```py
o = object.__new__(object, 1)
```

Result:

```
TypeError: object() takes no arguments
```

Observation: The error message is different then what we got before. This says "no arguments", the other says "exactly one argument".

Alternatively, we can create an object by hand skipping the meta-class:

```py
y = Y.__new__(Y, 3)
print("Y.__new__(Y, 3) ", y)
y.__init__(3)
print("y.__init__(3)   ", y.arg)
```

Result:

```
Y.__new__(Y, 3)  <__main__.Y object at 0x0000020ED770BD40>
y.__init__(3)    3
```

Here we clearly see `__new__` can accept additional parameters and ignore them.

So let's compare to manual instance creation of `B`:

```py
b = B.__new__(B, 5)
print("B.__new__(B, 5) ", b)
b.__init__(5)
print("b.__init__(5)   ", b.arg)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\newIstKomisch.py", line 51, in <module>
    b = B.__new__(B, 5)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

**Question 2: How can the same method have different behavior and exception handling?**

---

**Additional notes:**

- All behavior is implemented in `M.__new__` or swapped `XXX.__new__` methods instead of `M.__call__`, so the object creation time isn't influenced. Modifying the meta-classes call would have a huge performance impact.

---

**Attachements:**

- [Full reproducer file](https://gist.github.com/Paebbels/72ac61916134a75fbcb57d265e443733)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is sure a lot of research for a question.

But the answer is more simple:
`object`s `__new__` and `__init__` simply special case the "forgiveness of extra arguments" in a way that it feels natural to create new classes with a custom `__init__` method, with no need to fiddle with `__new__`.

So, in short, `object` new checks if the class it is instantiating have a custom `__init__` and no custom `__new__` - if so, it "forgives" extra args and kwargs. And object's default `__init__` does the converse: it checks if the class it is "initting" have a custom `__new__` and no custom `__init__`. If so it also forgives (and forgets) about any extra parameters.  The "custom" verification here simply checks if there is a `__new__` method present in any class' **dict** in the `__mro__` - so that even setting the same `object.__new__` class in a subclass won't work.

This strange-sounding special case is needed, and is baked in since a long-time in Python, because without it, whenever creating a class with a `__init__` method taking arguments, without implementing also a `__new__` method that would fail - so the case for "simplify class customization" by having a simpler `__init__` method rather than modifying `__new__` would be moot.

Here are a few examples on the REPL that make that clear:

```
In [11]: class A(object): pass

In [12]: b = A.__new__(A, 3)

TypeError (...)              

TypeError: A() takes no arguments
# There is no custom `__init__`, so it fails

In [13]: class A(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, *args):
    ...:         pass
    ...: 

In [14]: b = A.__new__(A, 3)
# There was a custom `__init__` so, object.__new__ forgives us. 

# and finally your case, both a __new__ and __init__ even if `cls.__new__ is object.__new__` is true, errors:

In [17]: class A(object):
    ...:     def __new__(cls, *args):
    ...:         raise NotImplementedError()
    ...:     def __init__(self, *args):
    ...:         pass
    ...: 

In [18]: class B(A):
    ...:     __new__ = object.__new__
    ...: 

In [19]: c = B() #<- works with no args

In [20]: c = B(3)

TypeError              

TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)

# And just one example with __init__ to show the converse case:

In [28]: class A(object):
    ...:     def __new__(cls, *args):
    ...:         # I strip down the extra args:
    ...:         return super().__new__(cls)
    ...:     # no custom __init__
    ...: 

In [29]: b = A(3)  # <- works

In [30]: class A(object):
    ...:     def __new__(cls, *args):
    ...:         # I strip down the extra args:
    ...:         return super().__new__(cls)
    ...:     # with a custom __init__ forwarding extra args
    ...:     def __init__(self, *args):
    ...:         print("init")
    ...:         super().__init__(*args)
    ...: 

In [31]: b = A(3)  # <- errors out
init

TypeError  (...)
Cell In[30], line 8, in A.__init__(self, *args)
      6 def __init__(self, *args):
      7     print("init")
----> 8     super().__init__(*args)

TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

## And last but not least:

for your case, you can't simply restore `object.__new__` in a custom "granddaughter" class - you will need instead to check if `__orig_new__` is `object.__new__` and if so, use a custom `__new__` that will strip extra arguments before calling `object.__new__`.

Comment: `object.__init__` does not accept additional arguments. Your final `A` example is a bit odd; `__new__` should not be calling `super().__init__`, or passing `cls` as the argument. `A.__init__` never receives any additional arguments, as it never gets called implicitly because `A.__new__` returns `None`, not an instance of `A`.

Comment: Sorry - the idea is to call `object.__new__` from the class custom `__new__` - I was calling `__init__` in error. fixiing it now.  It was a typo-like error.

Comment: But I don't think `object.__init__` is forgiving in what it receives, rather `type.__call__` is intelligent in what it *passes* to `object.__init__` when appropriate.

Comment: It is not - I thought it was forgibing because the code was wrong. Now that I typed it correctly, the behavior is the same for object `__new__` and `__init__`  as I've written in the text above the code snippets.

Comment: If `object.__new__` checks whether the class has a custom `__new__`, then that check is wrong, IMHO. It should check, whether the  `__new__` of the class is identical to `object.__new__` or not. This can be the case because of inheritance -- or in @Paebbels case because of an explicit assignment of `__new__`.

Comment: Found the check: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L5436

It looks as if they check tests, whether `__new__` is identical to `object.__new__`, but maybe that check is too simple?

Comment: Yes, there they are, the two conditions. They can be read as "if there are excess args and (__new__ is custom or __init__ is not custom): raise TypeError(). Otherwise excess parameters are simply ignored.
The interesting part is that, Python-side  `object.__new__`  is wrapped in a "builtin_function_or_method" object that does not compare as identical to the C function in native code.